# Get all variables of javascript in JAVA

Tags: java, rhino

I am using rhino and Scripting for the Java Platform in order to allow the user extend my application.

However the user can write some cases eg `(ASTO.value>440) || (ASTO.bellowNormal)` etc...
The problem is that before running the script from my JAVA application using ScriptEngine
i want to get the names of all the variables! Because i should know which variables are required for the script to run...
I know that a regular expression would do the job but i amnt sure...
Please i somebody could help me figure out the java regexp to get the variables i would really appriciate it..

Comment: Sounds like you want to implement the Alien Autopsy antipattern: http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?messageID=10337966#10337966

Comment: Why do you think that regex is the only solution? Are other solutions allowed?

Comment: ofcourse..all solutions are accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution 
cx.getDebuggableView(result).getParamAndVarCount()
But it doesnt return undeclared variables:(

Answer (score 0):

We're doing something very similar although it is written in Scala and I can only give you some hints...

1. Tests are really important
2. This is one of our more complex tests: `listArg[Math.floor(4 / listArg[zeroArg]['f3'])]`
3. Variables that describe the design...

   ```
   // chars after which there may be an environment variable used
   private val NewScopeChars = List('[', '(', '/', '*', '+', '-', ',')
   // chars that signal the end of a variable name
   private val SepChars = '.' :: ' ' :: ';' :: ']' :: ')' :: NewScopeChars
   private val ExcludeStrings = List("new", "Math")
   private val LiteralPrefixes = "'" :: "\"" :: (0 to 9).map(_.toString).toList
   ```

I'm having [a problem with performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8558405/instantiating-rhinoscript-native-objects-from-java-scala) so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

a little late but you might be interested in this: http://ramkulkarni.com/blog/understanding-ast-created-by-mozilla-rhino-parser/